# Configuring Grails 3 for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails, jdbc

I've been trying to get grails 3 to connect to postgres and cannot get a connection.

This is in my build file: `runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5"`

and the application.yml datasource:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: 'org.Postgresql.Driver'
    dialect: 'org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect'
    username: 'okcomputer'
    password: ''

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm sure the database exists and the user/pass is correct, but am not sure what to do in order to troubleshoot.
A full stack trace is available here: https://pastebin.com/THrALVaE

(I'm using java 1.8 and grails 3.3.8)

Theres a surprisingly small amount of information regarding grails and postgres, so thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver name should probably be `org.postgresql.Driver` instead of `org.Postgresql.Driver`.  Class names and package names are case sensitive on the JVM.

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    dialect: 'org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect'
    username: 'okcomputer'
    password: ''
```